# Jenkins loses workspaces periodically, triggers unwanted build

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have builds set up in Jenkins that use custom workspaces (for the purpose of having no spaces in the path names), that use SCM (git) polling to check for changes. However, in what seems like exactly every 24 hours, I see a triggered build that has this polling log:

```
Started on Jun 13, 2011 5:21:32 PM
No workspace is available, so can't check for updates.
Scheduling a new build to get a workspace.
Done. Took 1 ms
Changes found
```

It appears to be scheduling a build simply to obtain a workspace (something I expressly do not want to happen) even though nothing has been committed to git. I have unticked the option to remove old builds, do not have a periodic build set up, and use SCM polling once a minute.

I'm stumped and can't provide more detail than this - other than I know the workspace exists on the machine. Is there any way to stop this from happening other than ACTUAL commits to git?

Comment: You could try not using custom workspaces and instead letting Jenkins manage the workspaces.

Answer (score 6):

The [changelog](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Changelog) for version 1.1.12 indicates that a workspace is no longer required for polling.  Upgrading to this version of the plugin fixed this problem for us.

Comment: Did it work? That referred bug is still open(https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10131) .Anyway the answer deserves an upvote IMHO.

Comment: @inger a now-deleted answer by Thom McMurray responded to your question: *Still broken. In my case, I'm running Jenkins via tomcat and when I bounce tomcat, my build queue fills up with all the jobs. The scm-polling.log show the same thing though, that there's no workspace when in fact there is. I'm running Jenkins 1.499; Jenkins git plugin 1.1.26; Red Hat Red Hat 4.1.2-44; java version "1.6.0_16";*

Comment: Still broken here too.  There is another bug referenced here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18079 I don't know of a workaround.