# Jenkins keeps adding job in the build queue and keeps building them

Tags: git, build, jenkins

We use Jenkins with Git, and all the jobs are configured as, every time there is commit to Git, clean the workspace and trigger a build. This scenario is working fine.

Now the situation is, don't know the exact reason why but may be on restart of the system, all the jobs keeps on getting added to the build queue like an infinite loop, then jobs starts failing.
(When jobs are triggered separately, they goes successful)

What can be done for the above?

I have given `POLL SCM ****` so that it takes the change from the git as soon as it has a commit, can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be answered by: [Jenkins loses workspaces periodically, triggers unwanted build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333989/jenkins-loses-workspaces-periodically-triggers-unwanted-build).

Based on this question, I updated all of the plugins and restarted my jenkins instance.  Things appear to be better now.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this looping effect of Builds in Jenkins tonight.  I'm running the current version of Jenkins 1.598 and using the current version of GIT plugin 2.3.4.

None of the settings have changed except for adding a token to the https within the GIT URL textfields.  I have a build-after option that runs a different build after the first build is successfully completed. I have 4 of these types of builds altogether which is 8 builds in total.  After saving settings for all of the token changes, I then ran the 4 builds simultaneously.  This is where the looping began.

I started noticing that the first builds would finish and trigger the secondary after-builds.  Once the secondary after-builds completed, mysteriously the first 4 builds were showing up in the queue.
I also made sure that I did not have any other build-after setups in the secondary builds pointing to the first builds.

So, in my case, it seems that there is still this looping issue with the most current versions as well.

SOLUTION:
As Dan Woodward pointed out, restarting the Jenkins instance in Services for our Microsoft OS server solved the issue.  My hunch is that after every setting change, it is probably a good idea to restart Jenkins even though this is not a requirement from Jenkins.  However, it could potentially resolve any possible issues such as this looping bug.

Comment: Running up to date Jenkins. Restart did not solved problem with "build queue loop"